# Unusual gapping with floats and text-aligns

Tags: html, css, alignment, space, break

I have my company name on the left and my email on the right. I have the email set up like this:

```
<div style="color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px; text-align:right">
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">E-mail</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; text-decordation: none;">newtrendphotography23@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

As I am unable to upload any photos, this might be hard to explain. There is a verticle gap (like the height of the company name) between the word "email" and my actual email.

Here is the entire (relevant) HTML:

HTML:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="background: #000; height: 80px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>
        <div style="color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px; text-align:right">
            <p style="font-size: 16px;">E-mail</p>
            <p style="font-size: 20px; text-decordation: none;">newtrendphotography23@gmail.com</p>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gap is because of margin and padding `p` element.

Use :

```
div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If you want ,remove gap between email and my actual email only.

So use:

```
div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div p:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ge99wmrp/)

Comment: I kind of wanted it to say email on the top line, and then newtrendphotography23@gmail.com on the line directly beneath but it seems my company name make a verticle gap between the two lines. I feel like I might have to do something with parent divs and flex positioning.

Comment: You are a legend! Thanks so much!